# Bootstrap cards aligned vertically not responsive

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have 2 bootstrap cards above each other, but they are not responsive in height. When I put them in a parent div and give that div a fixed height, the lower card with the table inside will exceed the height.
To make this more clear I've reproduced this issue here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-8h1b14?file=app/app.component.css

What I want to achieve is 2 responsive vertically aligned cards fitting in the parent-div, but can't seem to find the right solution without hardcoded calculations (which I do not want).

Comment: You mix cards and tabs together, seriously, why do you do that? As a result you wrap your table in 5! divs. Remarkable. Please consider reducings the divs, it might make it easier. If it is valid, that the whole allergyWrapper is scrollable, then simply add the `overflow-y: auto` style to it.

Comment: well in my application the tabs are actually functional and styled, so that's why. I might solve it this way but I would prefer to make the table alone scrollable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to make your `.allergyWrapper` a flex container with `flex-direction: column;` and allow the card to grow or shrink as needed.

The following css handles the card sizing

```
.allergyWrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.mycard {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then to get just the table body to scroll, I found [this article](https://medium.com/@vembarrajan/html-css-tricks-scroll-able-table-body-tbody-d23182ae0fbc) to be helpful. Then I had to make the table rows into flexbox rows to fill the width (recreating bs table style).

```
.mycard tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.mycard tr {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.mycard td,
.mycard th {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

**Next**

- Remove the table wrapper `<div style="overflow-y: auto;">`
- Add `.h-100` to each of the following elements

  - `table`
  - `div.tab-pane`
  - `div.tab-content`

[My fork of your stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-vmcpw6?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: After trying to implement it, I noticed that it scrolls all the content in the card, is it possible to only enable scroll on the table? I have tried to achieve it with flexbox approach but can not solve it

Comment: @r0699049 I have updated my answer to get just the table body to scroll

Answer (score 0):

just give the `overflow-hidden` class in the parent (.allergyWrapper)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-cjaupc?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: But then it cuts off the content in the lower card, which I def don't want.

Comment: if you give the fixed height to the parent, some portion will be cut, its the fact

Comment: so what you want?

Comment: Is there a way to make it fit inside of the parent without cutting? I am using this component as a library in a main application, in this main application this component is inside of a div with a fixed height (user can choose and set the height of the div), so I would like it to fit in there nicely without cutting contents

Comment: so if the content is more than your fixed height, make it scrollable

Comment: is it possible to make only the table in the lowest card scrollable? that's actually perfect case scenario. I have tried to become that but can't seem to find the solution